# How is fmt:formatNumber tag used?

Tags: jsp, input, format

I am trying to format a percentage to 2 decimal places and the code (below) I am using is not working:

```
<form:input 
     class="calculator-percentage-input"
     value="<fmt:formatNumber value='${percentage}' maxFractionDigits='2' />"
     path="discount" cssErrorClass="error"
/>
```

The value displayed in my input box is (percentage is empty):

```
<form:input 
     class="calculator-percentage-input"
     value="" 
     path="discount" cssErrorClass="error"
/>
```

Can anyone tell me how to just display the value of `percentage`?

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
<fmt:formatNumber var='myDiscountPercentage' value='${discountPercentage}'     maxFractionDigits='2'/>

<form:input 
     class="calculator-percentage-input"
     value="${myDiscountPercentage}"
     path="discount" cssErrorClass="error"
/>
```